# Cookie parsing low-level

Tags: http, cookies, http-headers, abstract, low-level

I don't understand cookie parsing back into a cookie string or cookies header that's sent to browser. Every stack overflow question mentions platform-specific solution while I am trying to go low level.

Alright so here's an example cookie string fetched from a login request:

> AWSELB=1fff5a66839f6934cf8dab76e45ffa97; Path=/,
>   jses_WS40=02668ebd-0715-46f1-8ddf-97acfe1a28e9; path=/; Secure;
>   HttpOnly,
>   AuthToken=EFKFFFCH@K@GHIHEJCJMMGJM>CDHDEK>CFGK?MHJ>>JI@B??@CAEHBJH@H@A@GCFDLIMLJEEJEIFGALA?BIM?@G@DEDI@JE?I?HKJBIDDHJMEFEFM>G@J?I??B@C>>LAH?GCGJ@FMEGHBGAF;
>   expires=Sun, 31-Jan-2021 01:58:50 GMT; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly,
>   FirstReferrer=; expires=Fri, 31-Jan-2020 20:10:30 GMT; path=/

It should produce following cookies:
`AWSELB`, `jses_WS40`, `AuthToken`, `FirstReferrer`

But how should I parse it back? What's the format? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Seems pretty easy to google with `http cookie header format`.  That found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie which documents that multiple cookies in one header are separated by colon+space `; `, and cites RFC 6265, section 5.4: Cookie as the source.

Comment: That's what I found as well.